# Table with ruby doesn't match

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying do do a article show, after the input we can see the table and the description doesn't match.

[The description does not go on wtih his string.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pXEl.png)

```
<h1> Tous les articles ! </h1> <p> <%= link_to 'Créer un article',
 new_article_path %> </p> <table>
 <tr>
    <th> Titre</th>
 <th>Description</th>

  </tr>
  <% @articles.each do |article| %>
 <tr>
   <td><%= article.title %><td>
   <td><%= article.description %><td>
   <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_article_path(article)%></td>
   <td><%= link_to 'Show', article_path(article)%></td>
   <td><%= link_to 'Delet', article_path(article), method: :delete%></td>
 </tr>
  <%end%> </table> <%= link_to 'Home', root_path %>
```

Comment: Not 100% sure of the question, but if you want the table heading to match the data take a look at this. https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Answer (score 0):

Add 3 empty `<th>` after description `<th>` and check if you insert empty spaces in front of description when you created the article.